# Limit access to IP address on azure vm after a Limit

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-nsg

We have a Virtual machine on azure on which a web service is running. Since last few days there is constant over 1000 request from a single ip on the vm due to which the vm responds very slow or sometimes stop. Is there any feature in azure portal to limit the access of an ip address on vm after a limit or any other option?

Comment: Do you check Azure NSG? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg

Answer (score 0):

Azure API Management is a managed service that allows you to throttle particular clients and also provides a lot of security and other features.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts